# Can not access wp-login.php on WordPress multisites

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm developing the custom plugin to customize the WordPress login screen using the WordPress customizer. The plugins worked great on simple WordPress but didn't work on WordPress multisite. The problem is whenever I try to access wp-login.php through customizer it redirects to dashboard admin-panel. I googled the problem but didn't find any solution.

Here are the screenshots.

***Simple  WordPress:***

[image]

***MultiSite WordPress***

[image]

Looking forward for your suggestions. Thanks